# Calling function in main view when an item is selected from a pop over

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, popover

In my application I have a main view that contains a toolbar button. When this button is hit, a pop over is used to show another view for the user to select an item. In other pop overs that I have used, when the user selected an item, I did not need to do anything involving the main view. Now I need to be able to call a function inside the main view that will change its display depending on the selection. Is there a quick way to do this at the end of the TouchesEnd for the view in the popover? Thank you for your help, I am new to objective c.

Comment: I'm thinking you could use a notification.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into using the NSNotificationCenter now to complete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to complete this using NSNotificationCenter.